# Implement OWIN Authentication in Existing MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I am currently struggling to understand how exactly the OWIN Authentication works within MVC 5.  I have read numerous articles, but it all seems as if they expect you to know quite a bit about this.

I want to implement Authentication in my MVC 5 app, but have not yet find a good tutorial or article explaining this.

I see a lot of mention about the UserManager classes, but not even sure what this is used for.

Do any of you have any code samples, or articles that you would not mind sharing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the stuff here fairly helpful:
http://typecastexception.com/category/C.aspx . There are easy peasy walkthroughs for authentication on both MVC and Web API in there.

I suspect that this question may be too broad and risks being shut down. You may want to take a quick scan through the material above and revise to focus it a little on some specifics.

Comment: Thanks, had a quick look through this now, and this is the type of explanations I need.  I will be able to go over this article in more depth a little later today.